# Dual boot Windows 8 and Fedora 18, Both OS's on separate drives

Tags: linux, windows-8, fedora, multi-boot

I have an **HP dv7 6051ei** notebook which has 2 drives in where one has Fedora 18 on it, and the other has Windows 8 on it. Currently my fedora drive is set as the primary drive so when the netbook starts up I auto boot into Fedora 18.

How can I dual boot these two OS's, and where do I even start? I don't have any experience with dual booting and I'm fairly new to Linux as well. So keeping the explanation more in plain English would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much its that.

Firstly check if your notebook lets you select which drive to boot from - if both installs have their own bootloaders, you can simply use the bios boot selection options to switch boot drives. If you installed fedora after windows, or update grub, the fedora/grub bootloader should show the windows drive as well for you to select from.

Comment: I do know that I can go into the bios and select which of the two HDD's to use as the primary. Also I did install Fedora after windows (Does it matter though since it's 2 different drives?). Currently GRUB doesn't list my windows disk, how do you update GRUB? Perhaps that will solve the issue and the Win8 drive will show up in GRUB...

Comment: Perform `sudo update-grub` and it should detect your Windows automatically, I believe.

Comment: @Marcus Chan - Thanks Marcus, I don't have sudo but I did run this: grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg Which seems like it detected my windows 8 hdd. Going to test it now...

Comment: Nice, the above command I ran seemed to have updated grub and windows 8 is now displayed as an option to boot into at startup. Thanks! Although Windows 8 is stuck on the startup screen.. But that's just windows for you.

Answer (score 0):

for dual boot you can either install both the os on one drive and keep other drive for another use.

- for this first install windows 8 and then install fedora 18
- fedora 18 automatically detects the windows and display in the grub screen
- if it's not then type command in fedora terminal (after mounting windows 8 drive)

  `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`

if you want to install fedora first and then windows then it can be done . you can add fedora 18 in windows boot loader by which you can found here

http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/